# How to create enum of operators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

This is my data model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const QueryCondition = 
    sequelize.define('QueryConditions', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        orderIndex: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        value: DataTypes.STRING,    
        operator: DataTypes.ENUM(...), // values: < > <= >= == !=   //how to define this ?
        fieldId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        formId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        year: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        sqlOperator: DataTypes.ENUM('AND', 'OR'),            
        
    }, {});

  return QueryCondition;
};
```

In this data model I have a field of `operator` which is used for all operators (values: < > <= >= == !=) as part of SQL query, this data model will be saved in DB to save sql query criteria like WHERE clause.

I wanted to know what is the best way to maintain this field values?

Comment: are you asking what labels to use for them, for serialization? as in something like `{ GT:">" , EGT:">=", LT:"<", // .. etc }` - ps: (LT is short for less than)

Comment: yes, that's what im asking for, what is the best approach to do it ?

Comment: here is a nice article with best practices for lombok and hibernate:
https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/